# React Native paper - how to style this radio button?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Alright, I'm trying to achieve this look where my options are left aligned and Paper radio buttons are right aligned:

[image]

To do this, I tried wrapping the RadioButton and the answer Text in the same TouchableOpacity:

```
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                  style={[styles.answer, {flexDirection:'row'}]}
                                  key={index}
                                  onPress={() => handleOptionPress(answer.id, index)}>
                                  <Text style = {styles.bodyText}>{answer.value}</Text>
                                  <RadioButton.Android
                                    style={{height: 100}}
                                    uncheckedColor={"#F0F0F0"}
                                    color={'black'}
                                    value="first"
                                    status={
                                      answer.id === selectedAnswer ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'
                                    }
                                    onPress={() => handleOptionPress(answer.id, index)}
                                  />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
```

But the buttons are still left justified and slightly too low:

[image]

Theyre also too small. I tried upping the height in the style property as mentioned by the docs, but this did not work.

How can I up the size of the buttons and right align them?

Comment: Have you tried using  {flexDirection:'row', alignItems: 'center'} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
   <View style={{flexDirection:"row",alignItems:'center'}}>
      <View style={{flex:4}}>
      //Add Text component here
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
      //your RadioButton compnent here
      </View>
    </View>
```

Don't wrap the entire thing with TouchableOpacity since RadioButton handling things for you.

Comment: Any idea how to make the radio button bigger?

Comment: To make radiobutton bigger try using `transform` and `scale` in styles

Answer (score 4):

rishikesh_07 answer was close, but text and radio button were not aligned properly, adding alignContent: center to the View that wraps the text did it.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignContent: 'center' }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 4, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                  <Text>First</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                  <RadioButton
                    value="first"
                    status={checked === 'first' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                    onPress={() => setChecked('first')}
                  />
                </View>
</View>
```

There's also [RadioButton.Item](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button-item.html), which does all of this without needing to write boilerplate code like the one above.

Example from docs:

```
<RadioButton.Group onValueChange={value => setValue(value)} value={value}>
      <RadioButton.Item label="First item" value="first" />
      <RadioButton.Item label="Second item" value="second" />
</RadioButton.Group>
```